# django ajax send data from view to template and display these value

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I would like to know how I can display data in django template like {{data}} from ajax post request.
This is how I handled the ajax request in the views
let say that I have a context data dict
context = {'value1': Model.objects.filter(field=value), 'value2': request.POST.get('valu') }
if request.is_ajax():
I would like to have the same data and display data into the template when the request is ajax
return JsonResponse(context)
I would like to display the same data in template as {{value1}} {{value2}}
but when its ajax request the data is not displayed anymore.
Please help to understand.
Thank you for all.

Comment: I found a new solution by working the user session and its work perfectly ask I expected.